# Plane Equation Where $D \neq0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given the plane equation:

$Ax + By + Cz = D$

It is said that if $D \neq 0$, then $-D$ represents the distance, in the direction of the normal vector, between the plane and the origin.

But seeing as though the equation of a plane is really just the normal vector dotted with a vector which lies on the plane (where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are the components of the normal vector, and $x$, $y$ and $z$ are the components of a vector which lies on the plane) how is it possible for $D \neq 0$? If the normal vector is perpendicular to the vector which lies on the plane, then the dot product ($D$) should also always be equal to $0$.

Why is this not the case?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "But seeing as though the equation of a plane is really just the normal vector dotted with a vector which lies on the plane"?

Comment: I will update my question to explain this.

Comment: Have posted a new question following on from this one here - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3336283/plane-equation-where-d-not-equal-to-zero-part-ii

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistaken. The expression $Ax+By+Cz$ is the dot product of the normal vector $(A,B,C)$ with the *position vector* $(x,y,z)$, i.e., the vector pointing from the origin to $(x,y,z)$. In general, the vector $(x,y,z)$ does *not* lie in the plane. In fact, it lies in the plane only in the case $D=0$. It might help you to draw a picture of this.

Another note is that $|D|$ represents the distance between the plane and the origin only if the normal vector is a unit vector. Otherwise the distance is $\frac{|D|}{||(A,B,C)||}$.

Comment: Okay I think I understand what you mean. The normal vector ($A$, $B$, $C$) and the vector ($x$, $y$, $z$), go from the origin to the position specified by their components, which if the plane intersects the origin, means that the vector ($x$, $y$, $z$) will lie on the plane, whilst ($A$, $B$, $C$) will be perpendicular to the plane. If the plane does not pass through the origin however, then ($x$, $y$, $z$) no longer lie on the plane since its tail is at the origin. For the same reason, ($A$, $B$, $C$) will not be perpendicular to the plane. Is this correct?

Comment: @RyanWalter Not quite. $(A,B,C)$ is always normal to the plane regardless of the value of $D$.

Comment: Okay, in that case my misunderstanding goes slightly deeper than I first thought. I will re-post an updated question later. Thanks for your help @amd and kccu

Comment: Have posted a new question following on from this one here - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3336283/plane-equation-where-d-not-equal-to-zero-part-ii